# Select groups using slicing based on the group index in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe with a users indicated by the column: 'user_id'. Each of these users have several entries in the dataframe based on the date on which they did something, which is also a column. The dataframe looks somthing like

```
df:
user_id  date
0        2019-04-13 02:00:00
0        2019-04-13 03:00:00
3        2019-02-18 22:00:00
3        2019-02-18 23:00:00
3        2019-02-19 00:00:00
3        2019-02-19 02:00:00
3        2019-02-19 03:00:00
3        2019-02-19 04:00:00
8        2019-04-05 04:00:00
8        2019-04-05 05:00:00
8        2019-04-05 06:00:00
8        2019-04-05 15:00:00
15       2019-04-28 19:00:00
15       2019-04-28 20:00:00
15       2019-04-29 01:00:00
23       2019-06-24 02:00:00
23       2019-06-24 05:00:00
23       2019-06-24 06:00:00
24       2019-03-27 12:00:00
24       2019-03-27 13:00:00
```

What I want to do is, for example, select the first 3 users. I wanted to do this with a code like this:

```
df.groupby('user_id').iloc[:3]
```

I know that groupby doesn't have an iloc so how could I achieve the same thing like an iloc in the groups, so I am able to slice them?

Comment: You only need users? what about df['user_id'].unique()[:3]?

Comment: I want all the rows for each of the first 3 users.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way based on crayxt's answer:

```
df[df['user_id'].isin(df['user_id'].unique()[:3])]
```

Comment: I was just about to post it ;)